# selected form - how to change variables value, when value of form is selected

Tags: javascript, variables, select

I want (number) to have different values when different option is selected. For example, number=1 when 1 is selected, number=2 when 2 is selected, how would I do that with JavaScript?

```
  <form>
        Select your favorite letter!
        <select id="numbers">
            <option selected disabled>Choose one</option>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
        </select>
    </form>
    <script>
        var number;
    </script>
```

Comment: Since you declared `number` as global, simple create a function that handles `select`'s `onchange`event. And in that function extract value and assign to var

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<form>
    Select your favorite letter!
    <select id="numbers">
        <option selected disabled>Choose one</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
</form>
<script>
    var number = document.getElementById("numbers").value;
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys/girs, but i dont mean that. I mean else: how can i do this - if option value = "1", var number = 1; if value =2, var number = 2.  After form i have a var number = 1. I want to rewrite it, if option value will be 2, than var number = 2. I cant rewrite. It dont rewriting.

Comment: My original code is this. The code on top is like example. I want to hear an answer and write my own code, but now i put my original code:

Comment: if "organization1" then bigBoss_ = "Steve"; But i cant do it. I dont know why

Comment: ['code']<form>
    <select name = "organizations" id="organizations" style="text-transform: uppercase; width: 312px;">
    <option> «organization1»</option>
    <option> «organization2»</option>
    <option> «organization3»</option>
    </select>
    </form>
    <script>

    function getOrganizationName () {
    var x = document.getElementById("organizations");
    var y = x.options[x.selectedIndex].text;
  
    document.getElementById("organizationName").innerHTML = y;
  
    getAttr(); 
    }
    </script>
    <script>
 
    function getAttr() {
    var bigBoss_ = 0 ;
  }
    ['code']

Answer (score 0):

The script you would need for that would look something like this:

```
var select = document.getElementById('numbers')
var number;

select.addEventListener('change', function(){
    number = select.value
    alert(number)
})
```

This would work in most modern browsers you may need a polyfill if you need support for older browsers.

See fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/rainb0w/LzL3ybfm/

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick and easy way to do it:

```
<form>
    Select your favorite letter!
    <select id="numbers">
        <option selected disabled value="">Choose one</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
</form>
<script>
    var number = document.getElementById("numbers").value;
    document.getElementById("numbers").onchange = function()
    {
        var number = document.getElementById("numbers").value;
    };
</script>
```

Notice that I have added `value=""` so that you can detect the variable as empty if the user didn't select anything, otherwise `number` would contain the `Choose one` string.